# Javascript: Call a method inside another method

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I have a simple app, that triggers a boolean and sets a task to completed:

But I want to be able use a "Complete All" Button and set every task to complete. This here works fine:

```
  completeAll: function() {
    this.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
      task.completed = true;
    });
  },
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avzMYr

But instead of setting it directly, I would like to use a method that is called like this, because I have a lot of other code that needs to be separated.

```
  completeTask: function(task) {
    task.completed = true;
  },

  completeAll: function() {
    this.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
      this.completeTask(task);
    });
  },
```

Yet this does not work, see here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVaMLJ

Any idea how to call the "completeTask(task)" method inside of the completeAll method?

Comment: Welcome to JS's interpretation of what `this` is. It isn't always that, unless you explicitly close over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the value of `this` inside the `.forEach()` callback is not the same as what it is outside. You can save the outer value of `this` and then use that saved version to get what you want:

```
  completeAll: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
      self.completeTask(task);
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use **Bind** for setting the `this` value in methods like this:

```
completeAll: function() {
  this.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    this.completeTask(task);
  }.bind(this));
}
```