# Cannot execute for loop in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am very new to vue. I am trying to execute a simple for loop, but for some reason it is not working. Any help will be appreciated. My code:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');
new Vue({

    el: '#adresponse',

    ready: function() {
        this.fetchMessages();
    },

    data: {
        classified_bids: {},
        accept_qty: {},
        submitted: false
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages: function () {
            this.$http.get('/api/getbids')
                .success(function (bids) {
                    this.classified_bids = bids;
                    for (i = 0; i < this.classified_bids.length; i++) {
                        this.accept_qty[i] = 0;
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By changing the for loop like so, this worked:

```
el: '#adresponse',

ready: function() {
    this.fetchMessages();
},

data: {
    classified_bids: {},
    accept_qty: {},
    submitted: false
},

methods: {
    fetchMessages: function () {
        this.$http.get('/api/getbids')
            .success(function (bids) {
                this.classified_bids = bids;
                for (var key in this.classified_bids) {
                    this.accept_qty[key] = 0;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the value of `this` inside the `.success()` callback.

You could try something like this:

```
this.$http.get('/api/getbids')
  .success(function (bids) {
    this.classified_bids = bids;
    for (i = 0; i < this.classified_bids.length; i++) {
      this.accept_qty[i] = 0;
    }
  }.bind(this));
```

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418460/javascript-call-a-method-inside-another-method/32419471#32419471)